# Scala: Is it legit to refer to underscore parameters as x$n

Tags: scala

Say I have this function:

```
val f = (x: Int) => x + x
```

Now, I can rewrite this expression as

```
val f = (_: Int) + x$1
```

This compiles because _ expands to x$1, x$2, ... internally, but is it legit to use x$n to refer to underscore parameters? Scala language specification 6.23 doesn't say any rule for this 'fresh identifier', so should this be avoided?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "legit". In my book, if scala specification doesn't mention it, it's not legit as far as scala goes

Comment: Food for thought: what would happen on a platform where `$` is not a valid identifier character?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not "legit".

1. The naming of "fresh identifiers" could change at any time without notice.
2. It is almost certainly a bug that the compiler chooses a "fresh identifier" that appears in scope.
3. This does not improve the readability or maintainability of the code in any way, and is likely to confuse the reader.

It's hard to imagine a reason you would actually *want* to do this.